Why is Haji Najibullah's case being heard in federal court in the Southern District of NY?
I have read this article a few times and am unable to distill upon what basis that a civilian federal court has jurisdiction to hear this case.
As I understand things, the facts are as follows:

The defendant is a leader in the Taliban.
He is charged with killing 3 soldiers in Afghanistan.
He is charged with kidnapping a journalist and 2 Afghan nationals in Afghanistan (though they were subsequently taken to Pakistan).

I understand that the attorneys for the case are both arguing for and against the defendant being subjected to immunity applicable to soldiers during wartime.
However, that argument aside, upon what basis is US criminal law applicable to actions that occurred within the sovereign borders of Afghanistan? I would think that if the matter were relating to military actions, then the matter might be heard by military tribunal. But alternately, wouldn't local laws apply for illegal actions taken within Afghanistan?
As I understand things, persons who were involved in the planning and execution of the September 11th attacks were charged with murder and conspiracy under the laws of the locales where those activities occurred. However, none of those elements appears to be present here, so I'm very unclear on the basis for this case's jurisdiction.

One of the charges against Najibullah is "hostage taking", which can be punished under US law under certain circumstances even if it does not take place in the US.  18 USC §1203:

(a) Except as provided in subsection (b) of this section, whoever, whether inside or outside the United States, seizes or detains and threatens to kill, to injure, or to continue to detain another person in order to compel a third person or a governmental organization to do or abstain from doing any act as an explicit or implicit condition for the release of the person detained, or attempts or conspires to do so, shall be punished by imprisonment for any term of years or for life and, if the death of any person results, shall be punished by death or life imprisonment.
(b)
(1) It is not an offense under this section if the conduct required for the offense occurred outside the United States unless—
(A) the offender or the person seized or detained is a national of the United States;
(B) the offender is found in the United States; or
(C) the governmental organization sought to be compelled is the Government of the United States.

In other words, since Rohde was a US citizen, and since the hostage taking was (presumably) aimed at compelling the US government to do something to release him, the US claims jurisdiction under Sections  b.1.A and b.1.C.
This extraterritorial jurisdiction for hostage-taking crimes, by the way, is a custom of international law.  In particular, it is explicitly envisioned by Article 5 of the International Convention Against the Taking of Hostages, of which the US is a party:


Each State Party shall take such measures as may be necessary to establish its jurisdiction over any of the offences set forth in article 1 which are committed:
(a) In its territory or on board a ship or aircraft registered in that State;
(b) By any of its nationals or, if that State considers it appropriate, by those stateless persons who have their habitual residence in its territory;
(c) In order to compel that State to do or abstain from doing any act; or
(d) With respect to a hostage who is a national of that State, if that State considers it appropriate.


Najibullah also faces charges of "killing an officer or employee of the United States" (18 USC §1114) and "using weapons of mass destruction" (18 USC §2332(a).)  Both of these statutes also claim extraterritorial jurisdiction (the former in all cases, the latter if used against a national of the US.)

Would 18 USC §1203 apply if Afghanistan had voluntarily prosecuted Najibullah themselves? As I read the Wikipedia summary for ICATH, it appears that a state must request extradition of the defendant for prosecution if no other state requests extradition. Presumably Afghanistan would not need to request extradition and could simply prosecute, but would such prosecution satisfy the US's obligation under ICATH?

@Pyrotechnical:  I don't think there's ever any obligation of a country to request extradition of an offender — only an obligation to prosecute an offender if there's no extradition requests, even if the offense took place outside that country.  See the text of the ICATH, Article 5.2.  In other words, if Najibullah had been captured in Madagascar (say), and no other country had asked to extradite him, Madagascar would have been obliged to prosecute him.
